# Excel Multiple IF and AND

Tags: excel, if-statement

I have this excel problem...

```
     if 0-20   and <= 0.15 DISCARD
     if 0-20   and >  0.15 REVISE
     if 21-80  and <= 0.15 DISCARD
     if 21-80  and >  0.15 RETAIN
     if 81-100 and <= 0.15 DISCARD
     if 81-100 and >  0.15

=IF(AND(C34<=20,C36>=0.15),DISCARD),IF(AND(C34<=20,C36>=0.16),REVISED),
IF(AND(C34<=80,C36>=0.15),REVISE),IF(AND(C34<=80,C36>0.16),RETAIN),
IF(AND(C34<=100,C36>=0.15),DISCARD),IF(AND(C34<=100,C36>0.16),REVISED)
 but yielded a "NO VALUE RESULT"
```

Please help me

Comment: Welcome on SO. Please edit your question to precise what you are trying to achieve, what your expect from your attempt, what error you met.

Comment: looking at your data, the way it set up, whatever you are comparing to 0.15 is common to all checks and irrelevant to whatever you are checking for the first range.  As such I recommend you first if be to check is something is less than 0.15. in the false part of that if statement I would start nesting your ifs to check on the range.  By the looks of things what you are checking is an integer that is >=0.  Also since you have exclusive ranges, you can just check the lower range break point and work your way up to the higher range break point since it will stop at the lower range check for true

Comment: Looks like you may have made a typo in your second if condition, I think you mean >.15.  looks like you for got the decimal there and in the last line as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(C36<=0.15,"DISCARD",IF(OR(C34<0,C34>100),"C34 OUT OF RANGE",IF(C34<=20,"REVISE",if(C34<=80,"RETAIN",""))))
```

The first thing that is checked is if C36 is less than or equal to 0.15.  If this is true it will return "DISCARD".

When C36 is > 0.15 it will then check against C34 values.  If there is a value of less than 0 or greater than 100, it will display "C34 OUT OF RANGE".  When the value of C34 is 0-100, it will then check in order if it is less than or equal to 20 and if true it will display, REVISE.  If that is false it will then check if it is less than or equal to 80.  If that is true it will display, RETAIN.  If that is false, by lack of options c34 has to be greater than 80 and less than or equal to 100 and therefore it will display "".

## UPDATE

```
=IF(C36<=0.15,"DISCARD",IF(OR(C34<0,C34>100),"C34 OUT OF RANGE",IF(C34<=20,"REVISE",if(C34<=80,"RETAIN","REVISED"))))
```

for the case of the 81-100 range for C34 and C36 greater than 0.15 instead of blank "", "REVISED" will now display.

Comment: The conditions are: <=20 and <=.15 it will yield DISCARD, if 0-20 and >.15 it will yield to REVISE, if <=80 and <=.15, it will yield to REVISE, if <=80 and >.15 it will yield to RETAIN, if <=100 and <=.15 it will yield to DISCARD and if >=100 and >.15 it will yield to REVISE.  The rest of the arguments are OK except for some data like for example the input is 80 and .16 supposedly it will display REVISE however it displayed NOTHING or blank.  There are issues if the input is above 80 and above .16. Thank you so much sir for the immediate response.

Comment: if I look at your table in your question, for results in the 81-100 range for cell C34 and cell C36 greater than .15, you are showing blank. your question states nothing about revise.  IF you want revise to display instead of blank like in your question, change the `""` to `"REVISE"`